# how to generate expected value in C

Tags: c, console-application

I am new to the C language and I'm trying to write a simple self banking console program. I want to make a function to generate an account number so I wrote the code below:

```
int first = 7856123490;
int accountNumber;

int generateAccNo ()
{
    printf("%d", first);
    first = first + 1;
    accountNumber = first;
    return (accountNumber);
}
```

The whole idea here is that when I call this function, it will get the value in variable called `first` and add 1 to it and replace the value of `first` and return that value as `accountNumber`.

As I expect the first time this function runs it should return **7856123491**  this value and the second time it should return **7856123492**. So how can I do that?

Comment: That number is too large to fit into most `int` implementations.

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: Use `#include <inttypes.h>` and the type `uint64_t` and the printing format `PRN64d` (`printf("%" PRN64d "\n", first)`).  The chances are that you have a 64-bit machine and using `long` will suffice, but using the named type ensures you get 64-bit integers.  The 10-digit number requires at least 33 bits to represent it, so it will not fit into a 32-bit `int` type.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
long int first = 7856123490;
long int accountNumber;

int generateAccNo ()
{
    printf("%ld \n", first);
    first = first + 1;
    accountNumber = first;
    return (accountNumber);
}
```

- `int` hase a very small size to take such a big number so we will add keyword `long` when declaring the `int`
- To suppress the warning while using `long int` with `%d`, we'll use `%ld` for `long int`

Comment: `long` may also be too small.  `long long` is wide enough for 7856123490.

Comment: Yes, for `long long int`, we'll have to use `%lld`, but for this big Account no., long is enough

Comment: Ayush, "long is enough" may apply to your implementation.  C allows `long` as small as 32-bit.  `long` is not enough for a portable solution.

Comment: The return type should also changed to a wider type.

Comment: @ZongruZhan, yes to use the function to return `long int`, the function has to be made `long int generateAccNo(){...}`, and `long long int` can be used in a similar way

Answer (score 3):

A more portable solution: use fixed-length type in the <inttypes.h>.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int64_t first = 7856123490;
int64_t accountNumber;

int64_t generateAccNo() {
  first = first + 1;
  accountNumber = first;
  return (accountNumber);
}

#define TEST_CNT 10
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < TEST_CNT; ++i) {
    int64_t res = generateAccNo();
    printf("%" PRId64 " %016" PRIX64 "\n", res, (uint64_t) res);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%ld %016X\n", res, res` is meant to match a `long` and `unsigned`, yet `res` is `int64_t`.  This leads to _undefined behavior_ and implies code is not compiled with all warnings enabled.  Better enable all warnings and use  `<inttypes.h>` and `printf("%" PRId64 " %016" PRIX64 "\n", res, (unsigned long long) res);` - or use `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Yes, PRId64 and PRIX64 remove the warnings.

Comment: `%016" PRIX64` makes sense with `uint64_t` and `"%lX:` with `(long unsigned) res`, but not `%016" PRIX64` with `(long unsigned) res`.  Suggest `%016" PRIX64` with `(uint64_t) res`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach to work with big number, it will work even if you have `N` digits bank account

```
void big_number_inc(char * const big_number, const int size) {
    int i = size - 1;

    big_number[i]++;
    while ((i >= 0) && (big_number[i] > ASCII_9)) {
        big_number[i--] = ASCII_0;
        if (i >= 0) big_number[i]++;
    }
}
```

Full ref. code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x)       (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
#define ASCII_0             48      // '0' assci value
#define ASCII_9             57      // '9' assci value

// internal use (debug only)
static void inline big_number_print(const char *const big_number, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c ", big_number[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void big_number_inc(char * const big_number, const int size) {
    int i = size - 1;

    big_number[i]++;
    while ((i >= 0) && (big_number[i] > ASCII_9)) {
        big_number[i--] = ASCII_0;
        if (i >= 0) big_number[i]++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // note: if max length of number doesn't match initial string length - 1, 
    // fill remaining with '0' or revert and start working from offset 0
    char number[] = { '0', '0', '7', '8', '5', '6', '1', '2', '3', '4', '9', '0' };

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        big_number_inc(number, ARRAY_SIZE(number));

        // wanna see the result
        big_number_print(number, ARRAY_SIZE(number));
    }

    return 0;
}
```